# Find the value of second array according to first array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have model say Data it has three attributes 1)Date 2)Entity 3)value
I am fetching the data for 3 different dates

```
Date1-Any user selected date
Date2-Same date a year earlier
Date3-Same date three years earlier
```

I am trying to make a table according to the highest value for first date
i.e we are sorting the values for the first date and then displaying the entity according to that value.

Table example

```
**Entity** **date1 value** **date2 value** **date3 value**
```

In second column we will match the entity of the first column and the find the value of that entity for the second data.

My Problem is I have 80 entities and I have to run a loop for each column.so its taking a long time to load.

Can anyone help me out to achieve this thing easily without so many loops.

Controller:

```
 @field_1 = Data.where(:date=> @date.to_date).sort_by{|i| -i[:value].to_f}
 @entity_1=@field_1.pluck('entity')
 @field_2 = @entity_1.map{|i| Data.where(:entity=>i,:date=> @date_2.to_date)}
 @field_3 = @entity_1.map{|i| Data.where(:entity=>i,:date=> @date_3.to_date)}
 @field_4 = @entity_1.map{|i| Data.where(:entity=>i,:date=> @date_4.to_date)}
```

view

```
<%@entity_data.each.with_index do |entity_data,index|%>
  <td><%=entity_data.entity%></td>
  <td><%=entity_data.value%></td>
  <td><%=@field_2[index].first.value%></td>
....so on
<%end%>
```

Comment: can you post your code? what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused about why you want to get data like this but a better way would be :

```
@field_1 = Data.where(:date=> @date.to_date).sort_by{|i| -i[:value].to_f}
 @entity_1=@field_1.pluck('entity')
dates = [@date_2.to_date,@date_3.to_date,@date_4.to_date]
data = Data.where("entity IN (?) AND date IN (?)", @entity_1, dates)
@field_2, @field_3, @field_4 = []
data.map do |item|
@field_2 << item if item.date == @date_2
@field_3 << item if item.date == @date_3
@field_4 << item if item.date == @date_4
end
```

Hopefully this will help as 2 db queries are removed but we can make it more efficient. For that i need more details actually what you want to achieve.